# How to create matrix-like group of checkboxes with blank spaces in some cells in shiny?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I am trying to show a group of checkboxes in the form of a Periodic Table. This because I want to do a program that uses the selected elements to process stuff. Something like this:

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
tabPanel("Elements",

fluidRow(column(1, "Tabla Periodica")),

fluidRow(
    column(width = 1,
              checkboxGroupInput("g1", "", choices=c("H" = 1, "Li" = 2, "Na" = 3, "K" = 3, "Rb" = 3, "Cs" = 3, "Fr" = 3))
    ),   
    column(width = 1,   
              tags$div(HTML("<div style=\"width:10px;height:25px;\"></div>")),
              checkboxGroupInput("g2", "", choices=c("Be" = 2, "Mg" = 2, "Ca" = 2, "Sr" = 2, "Ba" = 2, "Ra" = 2))
    ),

  column(width = 3, offset = 0, 
         tags$div(HTML("<div style=\"width:10px;height:75px;\"></div>")),
            splitLayout(
             checkboxGroupInput("g3", "", choices=c("Sc" = 2, "Y" = 2, "La" = 2, "Ac" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g4", "", choices=c("Ti" = 2, "Zr" = 2, "Hf" = 2, "Rf" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g5", "", choices=c("V" = 2, "Nb" = 2, "Ta" = 2, "Db" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g6", "", choices=c("Cr" = 2, "Mo" = 2, "W" = 2, "Sg" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g7", "", choices=c("Mn" = 2, "Tc" = 2, "Re" = 2, "Bh" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g8", "", choices=c("Fe" = 2, "Ru" = 2, "Os" = 2, "Hs" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g9", "", choices=c("Co" = 2, "Rh" = 2, "Ir" = 2, "Mt" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g10", "", choices=c("Ni" = 2, "Pd" = 2, "Pt" = 2, "Ds" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g11", "", choices=c("Cu" = 2, "Ag" = 2, "Au" = 2, "Rg" = 2)),
             checkboxGroupInput("g12", "", choices=c("Zn" = 2, "Cd" = 2, "Hg" = 2, "Cn" = 2))
            )
        ),

        column(2,
         tags$div(HTML("<div style=\"width:10px;height:25px;\"></div>")),
         splitLayout(

         checkboxGroupInput("g13", "", choices=c("B" = 2, "Al" = 2, "Ga" = 2, "In" = 2, "Ti" = 2, "Nh" = 2)),
         checkboxGroupInput("g14", "", choices=c("C" = 2, "Si" = 2, "Ge" = 2, "Sn" = 2, "Pb" = 2, "Fl" = 2)),
         checkboxGroupInput("g15", "", choices=c("N" = 2, "P" = 2, "As" = 2, "Sb" = 2, "Bi" = 2, "Mc" = 2)),
         checkboxGroupInput("g16", "", choices=c("O" = 2, "S" = 2, "Se" = 2, "Te" = 2, "Po" = 2, "Lv" = 2)),
         checkboxGroupInput("g17", "", choices=c("F" = 2, "Cl" = 2, "Br" = 2, "I" = 2, "At" = 2, "Ts" = 2))

         ),
        column(1,checkboxGroupInput("g18", "", choices=c("He" = 2, "Ne" = 2, "Ar" = 2, "Kr" = 2, "Xe" = 2, "Rn" = 2, "Og" = 2))
         )
      )
    )
)
```

But it results in something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my way of doing it. The main periodic table has 7 rows and 18 columns. Based on that one can assume the periodic table to be made of 7x18 = 126 cells where each cell either contains an element or is blank. I am assigning a 5% (of screen width) width to each cell which for 18 columns would cover 90% of screen width.

Each `checkBox` is independent (not using `checkBoxGroupInput`) and `output$show_element_selections` shows how you can determine user selected elements. Since element symbols are by definition unique they can directly server as button IDs.

You'll need to put everything outside `shinyApp()` in `global.R` assuming you have UI in `ui.R` and server in `server.R`.

So here's the code -

```
library(shiny)

spaceFun <- function(width = "5%") {
  s <- paste0("display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: ", width, ";")
  tags$div(style = s, HTML("<br>"))
}

checkBoxFun <- function(btn_id = NULL, lab = NULL, width = "5%") {
  s <- paste0("display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: ", width, ";")
  tags$div(style = s, checkboxInput(btn_id, label = lab, value = F))
}

# define ui for each of perodic table cell
# cb stands for checkbox and sp stands for space
ui_type_by_cell <- c("cb", rep("sp", 16), "cb", # periodic table row 1
             "cb", "cb", rep("sp", 10), rep("cb", 6), # periodic table row 2
             "cb", "cb", rep("sp", 10), rep("cb", 6), # periodic table row 3
             rep("cb", 18), # periodic table row 4
             rep("cb", 18), # periodic table row 5
             rep("cb", 18), # periodic table row 6
             rep("cb", 18) # periodic table row 7
            )
elements <- c("H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na", 
              "Mg", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca", "Sc", "Ti", 
              "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", 
              "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y", "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru", 
              "Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I", "Xe", "Cs", 
              "Ba", "La", "Hf", "Ta", "W", "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au", "Hg", 
              "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "Ac", "Rf", "Db", 
              "Sg", "Bh", "Hs", "Mt", "Ds", "Rg", "Cn", "Nh", "Fl", "Mc", "Lv", 
              "Ts", "Og")
btn_labels <- rep("", length(ui_type_by_cell))
btn_labels[ui_type_by_cell == "cb"] <- elements

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(style = "width: 1350px; margin: auto;",
      lapply(seq_along(ui_type_by_cell), function(a) {
        if(ui_type_by_cell[a] == "sp") {
          spaceFun()
        } else {
          checkBoxFun(btn_id = btn_labels[a], lab = btn_labels[a])
        }
      })      
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("show_selected_elements")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$show_selected_elements <- renderPrint({
      btn_status <- unlist(sapply(btn_labels[ui_type_by_cell == "cb"], function(x) input[[x]]))
      names(which(btn_status))
    })
  }
)
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it seems this solution is screen-size dependent. Is there a way to do it more responsive? Because When I run the code in my computer, I don't get what you are showing in the image you posted.

Comment: What is your screen size? If it's too small it wont fit horizontally and will overflow. You can add a horizontal scroll if you want to maintain the layout for small screens.

Comment: It is pretty big: 17.3” And I think it doesn't overflow, but, even so, the rows messed up. If I reduce the size of the window, then it takes the appropriate form.

Comment: okay, I just tried on my 21" and see what you mean. I'll see if I can fix this later today. I developed this on my 15" laptop and looked fine there.

Comment: I have edited the code to limit layout width to 1350px. Widths from 750px to 1380px seem to work fine. Hope this meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have changed the last splitlayout code.

The total code is :

```
if (interactive()) {
     library(shiny)

  shinyApp(
   ui = fluidPage(
     tabPanel("Elements",

              fluidRow(column(1, "Tabla Periodica")),

              fluidRow(
                width=12,
                column(width = 1,
                       checkboxGroupInput("g1", "", choices=c("H" = 1, "Li" = 2, "Na" = 3, "K" = 3, "Rb" = 3, "Cs" = 3, "Fr" = 3))
                ),   
                column(width = 1,   
                       tags$div(HTML("<div style=\"width:10px;height:25px;\"></div>")),
                       checkboxGroupInput("g2", "", choices=c("Be" = 2, "Mg" = 2, "Ca" = 2, "Sr" = 2, "Ba" = 2, "Ra" = 2))
                ),

                column(width = 3, offset = 0, 
                       tags$div(HTML("<div style=\"width:10px;height:75px;\"></div>")),
                       splitLayout(
                         checkboxGroupInput("g3", "", choices=c("Sc" = 2, "Y" = 2, "La" = 2, "Ac" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g4", "", choices=c("Ti" = 2, "Zr" = 2, "Hf" = 2, "Rf" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g5", "", choices=c("V" = 2, "Nb" = 2, "Ta" = 2, "Db" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g6", "", choices=c("Cr" = 2, "Mo" = 2, "W" = 2, "Sg" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g7", "", choices=c("Mn" = 2, "Tc" = 2, "Re" = 2, "Bh" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g8", "", choices=c("Fe" = 2, "Ru" = 2, "Os" = 2, "Hs" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g9", "", choices=c("Co" = 2, "Rh" = 2, "Ir" = 2, "Mt" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g10", "", choices=c("Ni" = 2, "Pd" = 2, "Pt" = 2, "Ds" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g11", "", choices=c("Cu" = 2, "Ag" = 2, "Au" = 2, "Rg" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g12", "", choices=c("Zn" = 2, "Cd" = 2, "Hg" = 2, "Cn" = 2))
                       )
                ),

                column(2,
                       tags$div(HTML("<div style=\"width:10px;height:25px;\"></div>")),
                       splitLayout(

                         checkboxGroupInput("g13", "", choices=c("B" = 2, "Al" = 2, "Ga" = 2, "In" = 2, "Ti" = 2, "Nh" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g14", "", choices=c("C" = 2, "Si" = 2, "Ge" = 2, "Sn" = 2, "Pb" = 2, "Fl" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g15", "", choices=c("N" = 2, "P" = 2, "As" = 2, "Sb" = 2, "Bi" = 2, "Mc" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g16", "", choices=c("O" = 2, "S" = 2, "Se" = 2, "Te" = 2, "Po" = 2, "Lv" = 2)),
                         checkboxGroupInput("g17", "", choices=c("F" = 2, "Cl" = 2, "Br" = 2, "I" = 2, "At" = 2, "Ts" = 2))

                       )
                       ),
                       column(1,checkboxGroupInput("g18", "", choices=c("He" = 2, "Ne" = 2, "Ar" = 2, "Kr" = 2, "Xe" = 2, "Rn" = 2, "Og" = 2))
                       )

              )
     )
         ),
       server = function(input, output) {

      }
     )
   }
```

The output is:
[image]

For your future references: Use [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but is it possible to change the width of the columns so those huge spaces there disappear? The column width is already "1". And can't find a way to have uniform spacing between columns.